# Multiprocessing or multithreading a for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, function, for-loop, multiprocessing

I'm brand new to the idea of multithreading vs multiprocessing. I would like to run a for loop, which runs a single function (with two input args) either across several threads or several processors (very unclear about that, despite reading all day). It's also further complicated by the fact that the function appends to a list outside of the function, so when I try to store the function as a separate file and import it (I've been trying 100 different flavors of pool.starmap, ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor which all seem to want it as a seperate entity). So if I don't save the function as a seperate file I get a `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'GetBits' on <module '__main__'` error and if I do save the function separately and import it, I have trouble with the output_list variable, where I often get a `NameError: name 'output_list' is not defined` error.

A snippet of my current, working code:

```
output_list = []
list1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] #These list are just arbitrary, my actual data are not sequential like this
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def my_function(list1,item_from_list2):
    global output_list
    do_stuff
    do_other_stuff_to_get_statistical_score_between_list1_and_item_from_list2
    output_list.append(score_from_doing_stuff)
    return output_list

for x in list2:
    result = myfunction(list1,x)
```

Running the for loop on some toy data works well and the expected output is generated (a list of scores). However, both list1 and list2 will be increasing exponentially in size once I start working with my real datasets and running on one sad little CPU means this will likely take hours if not days to run.

My best attempt so far (I've failed several times over the last 7 hours) for parallelizing the for loop was this:

```
input_args = [(list1, list2) for x in list2]

    def OptimizationParallel():
    global output_list
    global list1
    global list2
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        output = pool.starmap(my_function,input_args) 
    return output_list

from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
from Sams_functions import my_function

OptimizationParallel()
```

However, the output from the optimization function is really weird (a list of lists) but the correct scores are in the mess of the output. Additionally, the output_list variable remains empty and I need that populated with the scores. I popped in a bunch of print commands to see what was happening and the right results are being printed out, just not put into the output_list variable or the output variable from the attempted parallelization. And as a final insult to injury, when I timed the OptimizationParallel function it actually took longer than just running the for loop! (Which I would suspect means I'm probably meant to be multithreading rather than multiprocessing but as I said at the start of my issue, that's super murky to me)

Any help will be hugely appreciated!

UPDATE: Following help from @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have cleaned up the code a bit. The original code now looks like:

```
output_list = []
list1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] #These list are just arbitrary, my actual data are not sequential like this
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def my_function(list1,item_from_list2):
    do_stuff
    do_other_stuff_to_get_statistical_score_between_list1_and_item_from_list2
    return score

for x in list2:
    score = myfunction(list1,x)
    output.append(score)
```

However, I'm still stuck with the problem that each loop iteration takes a very long time and I'd like to run single iterations of the loop on different CPUs (maybe 4 or 6 at a time). I'm probably using the wrong keywords but I can't seem to find any tutorials to help me do that.

Comment: you should be aware that all your `global` statements are completely pointless and don't do anything useful. also note, using `global` is generally a bad practice, but in this case, it isn't even needed

Comment: "However, the output from the optimization function is really weird (a list of lists)" why is that weird? Your function *returns a list*. Why did you *expect* the output not to be a list of lsits? Note, your original function *uses side-effects*, the return value is pointless, since you are just returning a global variable (very strange, again). Ideally, you should use pure functions (they don't mutate global state or their inputs). Then using `multiprocessing` will be trivial. note, using global state will make using `multiprocessing` hard, since processes **don't share state by default**

Comment: This is why "Additionally, the output_list variable remains empty". You have to understand, multiprocessing uses.... mutiple processes. Imgaine opening up a terminal, and running `python myscript.py`, then opening up another temrinal on the same computer and doing `python myscript.py`. You've run two separate python processes, of course, you wouldn't expect something done in one process to affect another process (unless you go through pains to make that work someone). That is essentially what is happening in multiprocessing

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! I'll get rid of them. I was under the impression it allowed me to use an outside variable within a function.

And I was expecting just a plain list as output [1,2,3,4] but instead I'm getting lists of lists [[1],[2],[1,2],[2,3,4]] which is not what my for loop did, nor what I intended to happen.

And thanks, the analogy of opening up different terminals has definitely helped clear up how multiprocessing works.

Comment: So how would I go about perhaps doing something like:
for x in [a,b,c,d]:
    a <- calculated in one process
    b <- calculated in second process
    c <- ....
And then join the results from the four processes?